I need to create a percentage from yes or no dropdown answers
I'm very new to Excel and I'm trying to create an audit form, I've gotten the dropdown menu down.
Now I'm trying to create a score based on the yes or no answers. Each page has a specific amount of questions, so I'm looking to make a score per page based on the amount of questions.
As well as a score on the final page with all totals of questions and answers. For example, if i have a total of 50 questions, but each page has 10 questions.
I hope I explained this correctly..any help would be appreciated.


what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

That is a very unfortunate data layout. Issues:

You seem to have several "forms" on one sheet.
merged cells - these hinder more than they help

Your biggest problem is that you are focussing your layout on data entry, with no consideration of data analysis. Typically, you would use a form to collect data and then write it into a table.
Data analysis and data processing formulas will be a lot simpler if your data is stored in a table.
With a layout like this, assuming that your red and green cells contain dropdowns for yes or no, you can use Countif() to count the occurrance of yes vs the occurrence of no. You will need several different formulas, since your dropdowns are in different ranges. As I said, a table would be easier to process.
So, create the Countif formulas to count the yes and no cells on each sheet.
You can add all these up on a final sheet by creating a formula that references the totals in each sheet.
